# Convergence in measure preserves measurability

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I'm trying to prove that given a convergent in measure sequence of measurable function $\{f_n\}_n$ from a measure space $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$, if $f$ is (any of) its limit in measure, then $f$ is also measurable.

$\{f_n\}_n$ converges in measure to $f$ means that
$$\lim_n\mu(\{x\in X : \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)|>\epsilon\})=0$$

To me the main dificulty is that with this type of convergence I have no idea of how $f$ looks like at any point.
I'm not sure if this is supposed to be proved using the definition of measurable function or if there is some "smart trick" to use.  In the first case I take an open set $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ and I want to conclude $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable. I think that maybe $f^{-1}(A)$  can be expressed in terms of the functions of the sequence but I don't see how.

Any hint or attept is welcome, I've asked this question 8 months ago when I was taking the course of measure theory but I didn't recieve any atention, now I'm preparing for the exam and I can't still solve it.

Comment: This is a bit like asking to show that if a sequence of real numbers converges to $x$, then $x$ is a real number. What kind of objects did you define convergence in measure for if not measurable functions?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker well I guess you can prove a sequence of real numbers don't converge to $i$

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker and as the answer below shows you can prove that the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, so I think the problem is not meaningless. In fact this was one exercise of a problem set of the course

Comment: Yes, you can prove that a sequence of reals does not converge to $i$when working in $\mathbb{C}$. What space are you working in? That the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable holds in the space of all functions, so there we do not have any issues.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker well I guess it is assumed that we are working with the space of all function here as well

Comment: But the usual domain consists of equivalence classes modulo measure zero sets of measurable functions. And $\mu(\{x\in X : \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)|>\epsilon\})$ doesn'teven make sense unless we know that $\{x\in X : \quad |f_n(x) - f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ is a measurable set- which is no guaranteed unless $f$ is measurable.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I understand, I suppose that problem is wrong then. Thanks fo clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Because the sequence converges in measure, there is a subsequence that converges pointwise, $\mu$-a.e. That is, there is a subsequence $n(k)$ and a measurable set $N$ with $\mu(N)=0$ such that $\lim_k f_{n(k)}(x) =f(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus N$. Define $g(x):=\limsup_k \mathfrak{R}(f_{n(k)}(x))$ and $h(x):=\limsup_k\mathfrak {I}(f_{n(k)}(x))$ ($\mathfrak{R}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$ denote real and imaginary parts). Then $L:=g+ih$ is a complex-valued measurable function such that $f=L$, $\mu$-a.e. This is the best you can say (in general) about the measurability of $f$; if $\mu$ is complete, then $f$ is measurable.